# Navigate straight to the bottom screen of a StackNavigator whilst providing params for the intermediate screens

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

### Background

I have an app with two StackNavigators: the LoginStack, and the MainStack. Upon the user completing login in the LoginStack, I navigate them to the next stack: MainStack.

If it's their first time using the app, the screen I navigate them to is MenuScreen (where they can navigate onward to VideoScreen by selecting a video); but if they've selected a video from the MenuScreen before, I skip past MenuScreen and navigate them directly to VideoScreen.

When skipping directly to VideoScreen, however, I find that upon calling `navigation.goBack()` from VideoScreen, MenuScreen is navigated back to without any navigation params. How can I ensure that these params are provided?

### AppNavigator

```js
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({ LoginScreen });
const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    MenuScreen,
    VideoScreen,
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginStack,
        MainStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "LoginStack",
    }
);
```

### Routing from LoginStack's LoginScreen to MainStack's VideoScreen

```js
const videoScreenParams = {
    originStack: "LoginStack",
    originScreen: "LoginScreen"
};

/* Called from the InitStack.
 * First we navigate to the MainStack, then we perform a sub-action
 * to navigate to the VideoScreen within that stack. */
this.props.navigation.navigate({
    routeName: "MainStack",
    params: {},
    action: {
        type: "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
        routeName: "VideoScreen",
        params: {
            videoScreenParams
        },
    },
});
```

### Going back in MainStack from VideoScreen to MenuScreen

```js
/* Called from VideoScreen. */
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

The problem: When VideoScreen renders, `navigation.state.params` is `undefined` because we never navigated to it explicitly.

Note that `navigation.state.params` *is* correctly populated if we navigate to MenuScreen before navigating to VideoScreen (i.e. if we don't skip the intermediate screen).

### Full reproduction

I've produced [an Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bottledlogic/react-navigation-going-back-to-intermediate-screen) as a minimal reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

[Official response](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6158#issuecomment-519771124) from Brent Vatne (a Member of the React Navigation organisation):

> you would have to customize the router for this: [API docs – Custom Routers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-routers.html)
>
> an example of how to do this kind of customization (implementing the actual behavior is up to you though): [Excerpt from Brent's React Europe 2019 GitHub repo](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-europe-2019-react-navigation/blob/5ccb336f994c42038f6ba4e99ff223e0aaf54790/sections/PreventingActions.js#L125-L141)

So it looks like I have some further reading to do before implementing a solution. I'll update this answer with a concrete solution once I've come back to working on this and have solved it.